# Angular 4 subscribtion onClomplete

Tags: angular2-services, angularfire2

I am new to Angular 4, i m quit stuck here with this subscription. can anyone tell me,  Why my complete function is not called

```
this.service.getMResult(key,itms.code, subcode)
.subscribe(val=>{
  total = total + val.val,
  console.log(val)
},(e)=>{ console.log(e) }
,()=>alert("oncomplete"))

getMResult(uid,examcode, val): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
  return this.db.list('/user/'+uid+'/', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'section',
      equalTo: val
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
this.service.getMResult(key,itms.code, subcode)
    .subscribe(
         data=>{
            total = total + val.val,
            console.log(val)
         },
         error=>{
            console.log(e) 
         },
         complete=>{
            alert("oncomplete");
         }
    );
```